# Calculate D-efficiency of an experimental desgin in R

Tags: r, experimental-design

I have an experimental design. I want to calculate its D-efficiency.
I thought R package AlgDesign could help. I found function optFederov which generates the design and - if the user wants - returns its D efficiency. However, I don't want to use optFederov to generate the design - I already have my design!
I tried eval.design(~.,mydesign). But the only metrics it gives me are: determinant, A, diagonality, and gmean.variances. Maybe there is a way to get from determinant or A to D-efficiency (I am not a mathematician, so I am not sure). Or maybe some other way to calculate D-efficiency "manually" so to say?

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: I've never used it, but `?eval.design` says it outputs "Dea - A lower bound on D efficiency for approximate theory designs. It is equal to
exp(1 − 1/Ge)." It also says "I, Ge and Dea are calculated only when X is input". So maybe you need to pass in an `X`.

Comment: I dont know about AlgDesign, but It's easy. I did it myself. just you need to provide the information matrix and compute the determinant or log determinant of the two designs.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a similar project. I found out this formula Deff = (|X'X|^(1/p))/ND in this [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/qcug/63922/HTML/default/viewer.htm#qcug_optex_a0000000394.htm). Where X is the model matrix, p is the number of betas in you linear model and ND the number of runs your experiment has. You could just make a code like this and it will do the trick.

```
det(t(X)%*%X)^(1/beta)/(numRuns)
```

I tested the results using JMP for my project so I believe this is the correct formula

Answer (score 0):

Determinant, the first result given by eval.design, is the D-efficiency.

Comment: Please give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Please read [answer] to learn about ways to make your answer more helpful.